# React how to specify animation @keyframes and classes locally

Tags: reactjs

```
function Loader() {
    var style = {
        border: '16px solid #eee',
        borderTop: '16px solid #3ae',
        borderRadius: '50%',
        width: '1cm',
        height: '1cm',
        animation: 'spin 2s linear infinite',
    }
    return (
        <div style={style}>
        <style>{`
            @keyframes spin {
                 0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
                 100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
            }
        `}</style>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Is there a way to specify `@keyframes` locally to the component (a component function in this example) without using an inlined string?

Also if you specify `<style>` inside the component render function does it have a performance penalty if there are multiple objects of the same class (or using the same `@keyframes`)?

The idea is to keep stuff inside `<style>` locally inside the component, I do not want to move it to the `.css` file, but at the same time I do not want hundreds of repeated class/keyframes definitions when only one is actually sufficient.

Answer (score 21):

This is not possible without writing a helper function or using some standard library that can inject keyframes, as browser options for this are still experimental and not widely supported, such as **animate** function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate

When importing them from another file, such as css, or a JS file by using CSS modules, Webpack usually does the injection heavy lifting for you.

I would suggest that you either DO import the CSS file, or to check out styled components helper function for this purpose.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { keyframes } from "styled-components";

function Loader() {
  var spin = keyframes`
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
`;

  var styles = {
    border: "16px solid #eee",
    borderTop: "16px solid #3ae",
    borderRadius: "50%",
    width: "1cm",
    height: "1cm",
    animation: `${spin} 2s linear infinite`
  };

  return <div style={styles} />;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Loader />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Any idea why this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75789918/it-seems-you-are-interpolating-a-keyframe-declaration-into-an-untagged-string) is not working anymre?

Answer (score 14):

You can do it basically the same way you already are, just declare a `Keyframes` component to neaten up your client code.  Some usage:

```
<Keyframes name="oscillate" from={{ opacity: 0.9 }} to={{ opacity: 0.2 }} />
```

or

```
<Keyframes name="oscillate" _0={{ opacity: 0.9 }} _100={{ opacity: 0.2 }} />
```

You need the underscore or some other letter in front of the percentage values but it's otherwise the same.  The component cycles through all its props outputting the formatted css.  Using jsx, React has a special CSS object type which needs to be converted to string, but otherwise it's just a component.

```
import * as React from "react";

interface IProps {
  name: string;
  [key: string]: React.CSSProperties | string;
}

export const Keyframes = (props: IProps) => {
  const toCss = (cssObject: React.CSSProperties | string) =>
    typeof cssObject === "string"
      ? cssObject
      : Object.keys(cssObject).reduce((accumulator, key) => {
          const cssKey = key.replace(/[A-Z]/g, v => `-${v.toLowerCase()}`);
          const cssValue = (cssObject as any)[key].toString().replace("'", "");
          return `${accumulator}${cssKey}:${cssValue};`;
        }, "");

  return (
    <style>
      {`@keyframes ${props.name} {
        ${Object.keys(props)
          .map(key => {
            return ["from", "to"].includes(key)
              ? `${key} { ${toCss(props[key])} }`
              : /^_[0-9]+$/.test(key)
              ? `${key.replace("_", "")}% { ${toCss(props[key])} }`
              : "";
          })
          .join(" ")}
      }`}
    </style>
  );
};
```

Comment: This is fantastic!

Comment: this is genius... i wish i could upvote 100 times

Answer (score 3):

Here's how we will achieve it without adding any dependency.

```
{/*Your Js File Code */}

import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React from "react";
import "./test.css";

class Anim extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      animationName: ""
    };
  }

  addStylesheetRules(rules) {
    var styleEl = document.createElement("style");
    document.head.appendChild(styleEl);
    var styleSheet = styleEl.sheet;
    styleSheet.insertRule(rules, 0);
  }

  clickHdl() {
    let animationName = `animation${Math.round(Math.random() * 100)}`;
    let keyframes = `
    @-webkit-keyframes ${animationName} {
        10% {-webkit-transform:translate(${Math.random() * 300}px, ${
      Math.random() * 300
    }px)} 
        90% {-webkit-transform:translate(${Math.random() * 300}px, ${
      Math.random() * 300
    }px)}
        100% {-webkit-transform:translate(${Math.random() * 300}px, ${
      Math.random() * 300
    }px)}
    }`;

    this.addStylesheetRules(keyframes);

    this.setState({
      animationName: animationName
    });
  }

  render() {
    let style = {
      animationName: this.state.animationName,
      animationTimingFunction: "ease-in-out",
      animationDuration: "0.6s",
      animationDelay: "0.0s",
      animationIterationCount: 1,
      animationDirection: "normal",
      animationFillMode: "forwards"
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.clickHdl.bind(this)}>
          Animation!
        </button>
        <div className="box" style={style}></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Anim />
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);


{/*Css Code test.css */}

.box {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-sun-qjo91?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for your solution. Consider [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71103740/5411817) to include an explanation to help guide visitors to the important bits of your solution & explain how/why it solves the OP's issue. Code-only answers are accepted, but discouraged. (In contrast, link-only answers are deleted). Good answers tend to receive more upvotes over time, when your insights help visitors solve their own coding issues, or prevent them in the first place, from the knowledge you helped them gain. You can read more in the help section, linked to at the top of every page

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on Ron Newcomb's answer. It seemed simpler to me to stick all of the animation props into their own explicit prop and not have to worry about any of the prefixing.

```
type IProps = {
  name: string;
  animationProps: Record<string, React.CSSProperties | string>;
};

const toCss = (cssObject: React.CSSProperties | string) =>
  typeof cssObject === "string"
    ? cssObject
    : Object.keys(cssObject).reduce((accumulator, key) => {
      const cssKey = key.replace(/[A-Z]/g, (v) => `-${v.toLowerCase()}`);
      const cssValue = (cssObject as any)[key].toString().replace("'", "");
      return `${accumulator}${cssKey}:${cssValue};`;
    }, "");

const Keyframe = ({ name, animationProps }: IProps) => {
  const cssRules = Object.entries(animationProps).map(
    ([key, value]) => `${key} { ${toCss(value)} }`
  );
  return (
    <style>
      {`@keyframes ${name} {
        ${cssRules.join("\n")}
      }`}
    </style>
  );
};

export default Keyframe;
```

And include it like

```
<Keyframe
  name="appear"
  animationProps={{ from: { opacity: 0 }, to: { opacity: 1 } }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way I found was putting a style tag in the code that select the div by class and add the animation created in it properties.

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Test(){
 return(
<div>
   <style>
{`
                .PropText{
                    display: -webkit-inline-box;                    
                    font-Size: 50px;
                    font-family: fantasy;
                    text-align: center;
                    animation: mymove 5s infinite;
                }
                
                @keyframes mymove {
                    0%   {color: #DE354C;}
                    30%  {color: #932432;}
                    60%  {color: orange;}
                    85%  {color: lightyellow;}
                    100% {color: #F3F3F3;}
                }
            `}
   </style>
   <div>
         <p className="PropText">
                   Sample Text
         </p>
   </div>
<div>
 );
}
```

Comment: `JSX expressions must have one parent element.ts(2657)`

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can add `:before`, `@keyframes` css styles in React component.

```
import { keyframes } from "styled-components";

  return (
    <>
      <style>
        {`
            .title {
              position: relative;
              color: #262626;
              padding: 20px 50px;
              font-size:90px;
              margin-top: 500px;
              margin-left:0%;
            }
            
            .title:before {
              background: #262626;
              color: white;
              content: 'ITWarriorShubham';
              overflow: hidden;
              position: absolute;  
              top: 0;  
              left: 0;
              padding: 20px 50px;
                -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0% , 30% 0%, 30% 100%, 0% 100%);  
              clip-path: polygon(0% 0% , 30% 0%, 30% 100%, 0% 100%);
              animation: slide 4s 1s linear infinite; 
            } 
                      
            @keyframes slide {      
              50% {     
                -webkit-clip-path: polygon(70% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 70% 100%); 
              } 
            } 
            `}
      </style>
      <div className="title">ITWarriorShubham</div>
    </>
  );
```

[image]